# Is there a way to use Solr's streaming API with spring data solr?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-solr

I have a use case where I need to fetch the ids of my entire solr collection. For that, with solrj, I use the Streaming API like this :

```
CloudSolrServer server = new CloudSolrServer("zkHost1:2181,zkHost2:2181,zkHost3:2181");
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("*:*");
server.queryAndStreamResponse(tmpQuery, handler);
```

Where handler is a class that implements StreamingResponseCallback, ommited in my code for brevity.

Now, the Spring data repositories abstraction give me the ability to search by pages, by cursors, but I can't seem to find a way to handle the streaming use case.

Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SolrTemplate` allows to access the underlying `SolrClient` in a callback style. So you could use that one to work around the current limitations.
The result conversion using the `MappingSolrConverter` available via the `SolrTemplate` is broken at the moment (I need to check why) - but you get the idea of how to do it.

```java
solrTemplate.execute(new SolrCallback<Void>() {

  @Override
  public Void doInSolr(SolrClient solrClient) throws SolrServerException, IOException {

    SolrQuery sq = new SolrQuery("*:*");
    solrClient.queryAndStreamResponse("collection1", sq, new StreamingResponseCallback() {

      @Override
      public void streamSolrDocument(SolrDocument doc) {

        // the bean conversion fails atm
        // ExampleSolrBean bean = solrTemplate.getConverter().read(ExampleSolrBean.class, doc);
        System.out.println(doc);
      }

      @Override
      public void streamDocListInfo(long numFound, long start, Float maxScore) {
        // do something useful
      }

    });
    return null;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Please let me know if you find the conversion issue.